# How override appearance of individual ECharts data points when using a dataset?

Tags: echarts

I have an echarts plot with many data points, which I am supplying using a dataset.  How can I set formatting options for only some data points?

e.g. If I wasn't using a dataset then I might highlight a single data point [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tezdr9m4/1/):

```
series: [
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: [
    97.7,
    {
      value: 43,
      itemStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000'
      }
    },
    92.5
]
```

But [using a dataset](http://jsfiddle.net/tezdr9m4/2/) I have no place for this extra information:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption({
  dataset: {
    source: [    
      ['A', 97.7],
      ['B', 43],
      ['C', 92.5]
    ]
  },
  xAxis: { type: 'category' },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{ type: 'bar' }]
});
```

If I try to set options in `series[type='bar'].data` then it [removes the data supplied by the dataset](http://jsfiddle.net/tezdr9m4/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing the same issue and not believing that this functionality isn't implemented into ECharts. I found a solution by using a callback function.
By defining an object holding the colors for each data point at its respective key I am able to return the color defined:

```html
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

let colors = {
  'A': '#FF0000',
  'B': '#00FF00',
  'C': '#0000FF'
};

myChart.setOption({
  dataset: [{
    source: [
      ['name', 'value'],
      ['A', 97.7],
      ['B', 43],
      ['C', 92.5]
    ]
  }],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: {
    type: 'bar',
    itemStyle: {
      color: function(seriesIndex) {
        console.log(seriesIndex);
        return (colors[seriesIndex.name]);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ecn3bw9/1/)
Additionally I added an optional header row to the dataset. This is not necessary because ECharts is referencing the first column in the dataset by "name". For additional clarity I added a logging statement to the function so you can gain some insight on how the dataset is processed when the chart is rendered.

---

If a simpler solution is needed it is achievable by creating an array of colors and setting the colorBy option to "data" in the series object - see ECharts [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.colorBy).
This simply iterates through the list of colors and assigns them to each entry in the set:

```html
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

myChart.setOption({
  dataset: [{
    source: [
      ['name', 'value'],
      ['A', 97.7],
      ['B', 43],
      ['C', 92.5]
    ]
  }],
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  color: [
    '#FF0000',
    '#00FF00',
    '#0000FF'
  ],
  yAxis: {},
  series: {
    type: 'bar',
    colorBy: 'data',
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ecn3bw9/3/)

Comment: can we achieve this for the itemStyle.opacity?

Comment: @erzen Unfortunately it is not possible to pass a function to the opacity property. You would need to set it from outside with via _setOption_. If you would like to adjust the opacity of the drawn data points you can pass the color as an rgba string to itemStyle.color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"